# Electromagnetic Induction from the relativity standpoint

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I understand how from the relativity viewpoint the magnet field is just due to the contraction and dilation of space resulting in a moving charge experiencing a force due to the electric field of other moving charges, but am struggling to picture how these concepts can be used to explain Induction

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically answered the question. A static field is produced by stationary charges. The force due to this field is proportional to the charge at the field point. Add motion to the system and charges don't respond to field due to the present distribution of charge, but how charge used to be distributed. Further, its multiple references points in the past that a given charge feels. The net effect is a curl in the electric field that gives you induction. Note the magnetic field effects motion parallel to it differently from motion perpendicular to it. Relativistic effects respect this distinction as well.

It's also important to keep in mind $\nabla \times \vec{E}=-\partial\vec{B}/\partial t$ is not expressing a cause and effect relationship, that would violate causality.

A fuller relativistic treatment of the issues in play can be found here: [Jifemenko's Equations](http://II%20think%20you%20basically%20answered%20the%20question.%20A%20static%20field%20is%20produced%20by%20stationary%20charges.%20The%20force%20due%20to%20this%20field%20is%20proportional%20to%20the%20charge%20at%20the%20field%20point.%20Add%20motion%20to%20the%20system%20and%20charges%20don%27t%20respond%20to%20field%20do%20to%20the%20present%20distribution%20of%20charge,%20but%20how%20charge%20used%20to%20be%20distributed.%20Further,%20its%20multiple%20references%20points%20in%20the%20past%20that%20a%20given%20charge%20feels.%20The%20net%20effect%20is%20a%20curl%20in%20the%20electric%20field%20that%20gives%20you%20induction.)